# How to convert a video from mp4/flv to mpeg/mpg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, flv

I download videos in mp4 or flv format but I need to convert them to mpeg 1/2/3 so that I can watch them on my special gadget.

I think I need a program.

any suggestion
thanks

Comment: @AkasAntony I would say it is clear that this [recent meta discussion](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6096/do-questions-about-file-conversion-via-software-available-on-ubuntu-belong-here) has affirmed that conversion type questions are on-topic, and should not be closed unless they are duplicates.

Answer (score 23):

Use **`ffmpeg`** utility, it's awesome.

**1. Install:** 

`sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

**2. Convert:** 

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.mpeg`

**PS:** For available formats supported by **`ffmpeg`**:
`ffmpeg -formats`

Comment: ffmpeg is going to be replaced by avconv ! ;)

Comment: what makes avconv more featured than ffmpeg ??

Comment: it seems they have merge. when you try some ffmpeg command, you will get something like :
`ffmpeg version 0.8.5-4:0.8.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Jan 24 2013 18:03:14 with gcc 4.6.3
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. **Please use avconv instead**.`

Comment: @riimzzai The ffmpeg and avconv projects have not merged and are very much still separate if you take a look at their respective websites.

Comment: @ mik : youre right it seems they are concurrent and ffmpeg is not dead ! see interesting info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-and-relation-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv/9477756#9477756

Comment: If the output has to be mpeg2, then must I use `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.mpeg2` ?

Comment: When I try to install ffmpeg, I get: "sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ffmpeg is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ffmpeg' has no installation candidate"

Answer (score 9):

this can be done with avconv

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

and then use (for mpeg 2)

```
avconv -i video.mp4 -c:v mpeg2video video.mpg
```

also, check the (impressive) list of audio and video codecs with avconv -codecs

Comment: thanks mate riimzzai ..because I am quite new to linux, could you please explain to me what " -c:v" means? I mean should I adopt this code to  my folder names?

Comment: `-c:v` is for video codec (you can replace it by `-vcodec`) `-c:a` is for audio codec, etc. check the man page : `man avconv`, you will see how this tool is powerful (you even can backup dvd).

Comment: thanks again I just use the first code but I got this  -----          sudo apt-get install avconv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package avconv  what should I do

Comment: sorry correction done : libav-tools. you still can install it via Software Center searching libav or ffmpeg or avconv

Comment: well I am unlucky today .software manager seems to be working but it froze even I cant stop it on screen..is there any way to stop this program and re-open it

Comment: go in the system monitor and kill it from there.

Answer (score 6):

There are many good video Converters wich can run CLI or GUI.

I advise you to give a try to [transmageddon](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=transmageddon).

To install just:

```
sudo apt-get install transmageddon
```

[image]

In the output field you can specify MPEG4.

---

Another pretty easy to use is [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)

[image]

To install in ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install handbrake
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `avconv` this way:

```
avconv -i file.mp4 -c:v mpeg2video -q:v 2 -c:a libmp3lame output.mpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Arista Video Transcoder on Ubuntu. Though not highly rated, it is very good for video conversion. I use it to convert videos to match PSP's supported framerate and it does the job just fine. Most of the other prominent ones strip the quality while converting to a lower resolution, but Arista maintains the quality even when stepping the resolution down to that of a mobile device's.